# Tensorflow should I separate object sides?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I'm working on a project that uses tensorflow to detect a specific object. That object can be laying on a table or any other surface and it has two sides, both of the sides look different from each other.
I'm following this tutorial to build my object detection model: [Object detection with tensorflow tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rgpfk6eYxJA)

Currently I'm on the labeling step and I need to know if I should separate the back and the front of the object to two different labels (I don't need to separate it for my code, I just need to know if it is the object I'm searching for) and what is the right way to do that with google object detection api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good way to start AI or Data Science projects is to start from easiest solution (although it might generate worse results) and then incrementally make it more and more complex.

Therefor personally I would separate them into 2 different labels `your_object_front` and `your_object_back`. This will not make your model to learn conflicting features so mind give better results on simpler models.

Another positive is fact that always you can merge 2 different labels into single one in simple script but not other way around.